# RNN file is missed from tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following the [RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/#run_the_code) on Tensorflow site. However, I couldn't find the rnn file named `ptb_word_lm.py`.
In my ptb folder, there is only `reader.py` there. Where I can find `ptb_word_lm.py`?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug, which we're tracking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6196

The short answer is that the code is now here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb

Comment: Although I can copy the file from `models` on GitHub, another bug arises. It said `reader.py` doesn't have method `producer`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py), by searching "ptb_word_lm.py" in Google.

It seems it was removed from the official repository in version recently, one can still find it in 0.12 revision branch [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py).

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't the official repository of tensorflow.

Comment: It seems it was removed from official repo recently.